# How to use an idiom in a paper?

Tags: idioms, writing

I am writing a short reflection and I'm describing a situation where I am joking around with someone. What I mean by "joking around" is playfully teasing. Would I just write, "I joked around with my friend"? Would I just use playfully teased instead?

Comment: This is borderline on-topic on ELU, perhaps being a better fit on Interpersonal Skills.SE. I'd be far happier with a tongue-in-cheek "I traded insults with my best friend Hawkeye', but these things are tricky, involving a juvenile-sounding vs over-incisive/misinterpretable balancing act.

Comment: If you mean "playfully teasing" what's stopping you from using that directly?

Comment: Not sure what the question is asking. Either phrase seems fine. Are you worried which phrase is good English? Do you want to know which is more formal or if one is too colloquial? Do you think it's socially inappropriate to talk about? Are you looking to avoid sexually suggestive language? By "short reflection" do you mean this is a formal assignment for some educational task, and you're worried what is suitable for that? If so, what task? Also, without knowing what you were doing with your friend, it's hard to know the exact terminology. More detail and context would be useful.

Comment: I was wondering if it was appropriate because it comes off as slang. But it may be okay because it is a short reflection based on personal experience where I'm writing in first person. I was just curious on the use of idioms in writine. But I will just stick with playfully teasing.

Comment: In a very informal register, 'I was joshing with my best mate.'

Comment: You ***engaged in** banter / badinage / persiflage / railery / reparteee / ...* We seem to have far more nouns than verbs in this area.

Comment: How can you avoid using idioms in language? Certainly not in English. If you need a model of a writing style that is colloquial and fit for a paper, respected national newspapers can serve that model.